# Python + ffmpeg TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, ffmpeg, stdout, popen

I'm sending a file to a function in python, and trying to save the results to a variable, but I keep getting that error.

I've looked over the other answers but nothing seems to fit. Any help is appreciated:

```
def ffmpegLUFS(fileName):
    subprocess.Popen("ffmpeg -i %s -filter_complex ebur128 -f null - 2>&1 | grep -n '.*' | grep -A 5 'size' | grep 'I:' | cut -d ':' -f3-" % tuple(map(pipes.quote, sys.argv[1])),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).communicate()[0]
    return
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/videos/videos/DROP_BIN/CHRIS/POD_Workflow_Files/WebContent_Audio.py", line 30, in <module>
    sourceLUFS = ffmpegLUFS(sys.argv[1])
  File "/Volumes/videos/videos/DROP_BIN/CHRIS/POD_Workflow_Files/WebContent_Audio.py", line 18, in ffmpegLUFS
    subprocess.Popen("ffmpeg -i %s -filter_complex ebur128 -f null - 2>&1 | grep -n '.*' | grep -A 5 'size' | grep 'I:' | cut -d ':' -f3-" % tuple(map(pipes.quote, fileName)),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).communicate()[0]
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Please include complete error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this part of your code:

```
tuple(map(pipes.quote, sys.argv[1]))
```

The [Python `map` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) takes a function and an iterable and returns a list obtained by applying the function to each element of the iterable<sup>[1]</sup>.  In your case, the iterable is a string, and the elements of the string are its characters, so the result of `map(pipes.quote, sys.argv[1])` will be a list of characters from your string, quoted as necessary.  For example, if `sys.argv[1]` is 10 characters long, `map(pipes.quote, sys.argv[1])` will be a list of length 10.

I could only see one `%s` placeholder in your command-line string, so unless `sys.argv[1]` happens to contain only one character, you will encounter the 'not all arguments converted...' exception, because the number of `%s` placeholders in your string differs from the number of values you are attempting to put into the string.

As I see it, the simplest fix is to remove the calls to `tuple` and `map` and just use `pipes.quote(sys.argv[1])` instead.

<sup>[1]</sup>`map()` can actually take more than one iterable, but for simplicity I'm ignoring this.  When given two arguments it behaves as I have described.

Comment: Thanks! this helps. One issue that I'm running into using just the pipes.quote(sys.argv[1]) is in the filename of the files, they have placed a "##" in the file names. The script is getting hung up on that now. How do I fix that? Here is an example of what I'm seeing when processing the filename: /Users/chrissmith/Downloads/TRAININGSKU_AbbySunderland\#\#157487.aif

Comment: @SonicMotion: are you sure it's the `#` characters it's complaining about?    Your filename has two odd Unicode characters between the 5 and the first 7.  Besides, exactly what do you mean by "hung up"?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the problem, the error I'm now getting is: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory - so the ## was my first thought. When I say "hung up" I meant, I was stumped.

Comment: @SonicMotion: in that case it's quite probably the Unicode characters I mentioned that are the problem.  I don't have your files, nor do I know exactly how you're calling the script, so I'm not sure I can help you any more.

Comment: This solves my unicode issues: 

'subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', fileName, '-filter_complex', 'ebur128', '-f', 'null', "'- 2>&1 |' grep -n '.*' | grep -A 5 'size' | grep 'I:' | cut -d ':' -f3-"])'